# How to tell in Facebook Comment Moderation what pages are being commented on

Tags: facebook-comments, comments

We've integrated FB commenting into our website, and a comprehensive list of comments appearing on individual pages can be found in one long list at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Moderation is working properly, but the problem is that the comments are not denoting on which page of the site they were posted. For example, there is a list of comments that say "Great article," but it's unclear which article was commented on. Is it possible, within the moderator tool, to see what page each comment is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the date/time of the post in the moderation tool. it'll take you to the page where the comment was posted.